# jquery Ie - object does not support

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, object

I have a mass of code which after splitting it all uop with try and catch methods, I have norrowed it down to the following :

```
try {
    if (typeof $('select') == 'object') {
        $('select').each(function() {
            var selOb = $(this);
            var dWidth = 170;

            if (selOb.hasClass('mediumDropDown')) {
                dWidth = 100;
            } else if (selOb.hasClass('smallDropDown')) {
                dWidth = 50;
            } else if (selOb.hasClass('longDropDown')) {
                dWidth = 250;
           }

            $(this).chemSelectbox({
                width: dWidth,
                removeClass: ['chemSideTip']
            });
        });
    }
} catch (err) {
    alert(err.message + ' : checkout_init() 2');
}
```

and in particular,

```
$(this).chemSelectbox({ width: dWidth, removeClass: ['chemSideTip'] });
```

I have, removed both options so there it's not that, yet my plugin works on all other browser bar ie.

does anyone know why this happens.

regards

Comment: A plugin I wrote - it's in the link above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all occurences of

```
attributes.class
```

with

```
attributes['class']
```

*class* is a reserved word in JS

Because of that you'll get a error "identifier expected" before(line 71 in the fiddle-demo), what will break the plugin.

Comment: JUST seen that in JShint... looking into it now. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Definatly part of the problem, but went through the JShint list and has sorted that now, cheers